# sql query when server timezone is before data

Tags: mysql

I have a query to data from a table in my database. The table grabs hourly data and populates the table. The problem is the data source is 6 timezones ahead of my server time. Therefore when I conduct a query for the last 7 days the results only go up to the specific time of the server and dont include the last 6 rows (last six hours according to the data source).

I am using INTERVAL 7 DAY. Any ideas on how to get the most recent data in the query results

Here is the query that I am using.

```
SELECT tb0.DATE DATE,
    tb0.value value_0,
    tb1.value value_1
FROM (
    SELECT a0.DATE DATE,
        a0.value value,
        a0.leaders leaders
    FROM head2head a0
    WHERE a0.leaders = 'issue1'
        AND a0.DATE BETWEEN DATE (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            AND NOW()
    ) tb0
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a1.DATE DATE,    
        a1.value value,
        a1.leaders leaders
    FROM head2head a1
    WHERE a1.leaders = 'issue2'
        AND a1.DATE BETWEEN DATE (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            AND NOW()
    ) tb1
    ON (tb0.DATE = tb1.DATE)
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set to your timezone with `SET time_zone = timezone;` per query as stated at [mySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-g11n-excerpt/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).
If it does not fit your needs, you could use [convert_tz function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-convert_tz-function.php).

Comment: This worked in the SQL query but didnt pull results in an app (wpdatatables). Any other suggestions? In essence, I just need to get the last 168 rows (24 rows per day X 7 days). Each row is date/timestamped